# How to avoid MySQL install warning in CentOS (Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID <hash>: NOKEY)

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

I am installing a MySQL server into a Vagrant VM with a CentoOS box and I keep getting a warning every time it is being downloaded and installed: *default: warning: /tmp/mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY*

The code that I use to install the MySQL server is the following:

```
# Disable default package
dnf module reset -y mysql
dnf module disable -y mysql

# Get the MySQL official RPM
curl -L https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/x86_64/mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch.rpm -o /tmp/mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh /tmp/mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch.rpm

# Install & enable the server
dnf install -y mysql-community-server
systemctl enable mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

Is there any way to make the warning go away?

Answer (score 4):

The warning tells you that rpm knows nothing about the key used to sign this rpm.

You can import the key to rpm db:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

And then just:

```
rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/x86_64/mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Take note, that the RPM KEY change on 17.1.2022 (see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106188)

Import the key now with `rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022`